# Error using gte projection option with an ISODate object n Mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, isodate

I have a collection with a timestamp field stored in the ISODate format. This database is populated by a third party. A subset of the document looks like:

```
collection{
    "_id" : "foobar/201310",
    "name" : "SomeName",
    "processedtime" : "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value" : 375439
       .
       .
       .
}
```

The data in the `processedtime` field looks like `2014-10-21T12:13:12.056790`

When I query this collection with the following query:

```
db.collection.find({},{processedtime:{$gte : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z")}});
```

I get this error:

> Unsupported projection option "$gte", "code":13097";

I get the same error when I change the `ISODate` in the query to "new Date" or change `$gte` to `$gt`

I am using version `2.4.6`, Is there some configuration piece or syntax problem with my query? I am also wondering since the data goes out to nano seconds is this a problem? I have looked for this error and no one seems to be reporting it with a query like this.

Comment: A correction, the field in my query only goes to microseconds, some other fields in the dataset go to nanoseconds but not the example I used here.

Comment: It looks like your dates are being stored as strings based on your output, but it's not really clear from the sample.  Can you just post the output of db.collection.findOne() so we can verify the actual content of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection.find({},{processedtime:{$gte : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z")}});` should be `db.collection.find({processedtime:{$gte : "2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z"}});`.

Comment: When I use this format I get no results at all although there should be hundreds of collections that match the search criteria.

Comment: @Kirt Hall, What's the data type of **processedtime** in database, string or Date? If it's Date, use `db.collection.find({processedtime:{$gte : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z")}});`. But just according to the output of your question , it's String type: `"processedtime" : "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", `

Comment: I tried this again, removing the ISODate constructor as your answer directed and this worked. As Adam pointed out the data is not stored as an ISODate object but as a string.  I will have to sort through the lexicographical sore order in my code. Thanks you for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

First off, your query criteria (such as `$gte` conditions) go in the first document of the find, not the second - which is why you get the projection error - you are saying to return all documents (the empty criteria field - `{}`) and then have an essentially nonsensical projection in the second field.  Basically, your query should look like this:

```
db.collection.find({processedtime:{$gte : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z")}});
```

If you wanted to only return specific fields, say `name` and `processedtime`, you would add a projection like so.  Now you can see why the original query made no real sense and threw an error:

```
db.collection.find({processedtime:{$gte : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z")}}, {_id : 0, name : 1, processedtime : 1});
```

Your sample document suggests that the `processedtime` field is in fact not stored as an `ISODate`, rather it appears to be stored as a string. That would mean your query should be:

```
db.collection.find({processedtime:{$gte : "2014-10-21T00:00:00.000Z"}});
```

It should be noted that this will make the comparison a little tricky since it will use [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) to compare string values, which can lead to odd results, but may be OK for your purposes.

To explain your lack of results, the string type comes before the UTC datetime type in the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), which means that if you look for strings "greater than" `UTC datetime` values, you will always get nothing.

Additionally, if you have an index on `processedtime` and run a query looking for a particular data type (`ISODate`), then it will only return results of that type.  Hence if `processedtime` is indeed stored as a string, then that query will also nothing, regardless of the criteria used because of the type mismatch.